# Response of rest api in magento 2.1.12 is too slow

Tags: magento-2.1, rest-api, response

Response of rest API in Magento 2.1.12 is too slow.

It take 15 to 20sec for load the data in website. I'm using default mode.

Anybody help me to how to increase speed of website?

Comment: have you enabled or disable cache from backend ?

Comment: I will set enable cache from backend..